# BSON Customer Serializer - determine if type is being used as Id field

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, bson, mongodb-.net-driver

I have written a custom Bson Serializer by extending `SerializerBase<T>`

When serializing, I'd like to detect whether the object being serialized is being used as the `Id` field for the overall document.

If it is, I'd like to serialize as a string.

If not, I'll serialize as a document.

Is this possible and if so, how?  Is this information available either thru the `BsonSerializationContext` or the `BsonSerializationArgs`?

Comment: I can suggest to separate your serializer to two serializers one for `Id`s another one for others, and using an interface for `Id`s ;).